# If a folder exists do this, else, do this

Tags: powershell

What am I doing wrong here?

I want to find if a folder exists on a group of PC's (including my own) and if it does, I want it to tell me the name of the computer. If it isn't there, I want it to tell me the name of the computer and 'Path is not there'

```
$Computers = gc 'C:\Temp\Computers.txt'

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    if (Test-Path -Path '\\$Computer\C$\Temp2') {
        Write-Host $Computer
    } else {
        Write-Host $Computer + 'Path Is Not There'
    }
}
```

The above tells me that the folder is not there (I know it is for at least one of the computers in the list).

Comment: How does your "Computers.txt" file look like?

Comment: Currently just two PC's on two seperate lines.  

TestPC1  
TestPC2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is the quotes you are using around the path you are testing.

Single quotes do not allow variable expansion, so it's literally looking for the path `'\\$Computer\C$\Temp2'` and not using the variable for the computer name.

Documentation on this: [about_quoting_rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)

If you update your code to use double quotes, the variable value will be used as you want:

```
Test-Path -Path "\\$Computer\C$\Temp2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the single quotes ( ' ) for the Test-Path -Path into double quotes ( " ), otherwise the variables won't be recognized